# Cant receive messages over a certain size with autobahn?

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

im having a problem with my android application which uses autobahn to receive messages from a Websocket server. The server uses libwebsockets.
I am able to receive messages which are "small" enough. So this is no problem, but once the message size is over a certain value, the app just stops to call `onTextMessageReceive()` method.
After that happened once, im also not able to receive anything else anymore. I need to restart my app in order to get messages again.

Does someone know where the problem could be?
I checked the parameters for `MaxMessagePayloadSize` and `MaxFramePayloadSize` and they are well over the size what im trying to send to my app.

Comment: What is the "certain value" above which you experience the issue? The 2 locations where AutobahnAndroid bails out on sizes are: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketReader.java#L237 and https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketReader.java#L360. Is that triggering?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer: I found that this certain value is 150 bytes, anything larger than this causes the problem. I also found a strange behavior. Because with the echoTest example server from http://www.websocket.org it works fine. When using this Server i can receive more than this 150 bytes, but with my libwebsockets not, the strange thing is that if im using another client, i can receive more than 150 bytes also with the libwebsockets. It seems that the problem is the combination of libwebsockets and autobahn. I found that im somehow stuck in a while loop at http://goo.gl/i9UbLU

Comment: I don't know about libwebsocket, but AutobahnAndroid works well with various servers - and it is tested for protocol compliance using AutobahnTestsuite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer myself.
My bad! its not a fault of the autobahn client.
I created a new protocol in the libwebsocket server, and there was an option set like this:

```
{
"new_protocol",     /* name */
callback_ new_protocol,     /* callback */
sizeof(struct per_session_data_new_protocol),
128,            /* max frame size /rx buffer */
},
```

I now changed this to a much bigger value and now its working fine :)

Anyways, thanks for your effort :)